# Ansible paramiko ssh stuck when to escalate privilege command

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-vault

I have sandvine devices based on freebsd I need to create playbook for multi-automation purposes but am facing issue when I need to escalate my privilege, the only way to escalate privilege is through this command `sv_enable sv_admin`it works like `su -` command it change prompt from `>$` to `>#` sudo doesn't work here, so when I run playbook and when it came to this command `sv_enable sv_admin` the playbook hang, I changed the default ssh connection for Ansible to paramkio, but without no luck still facing the same issue , I appreciate your prompt attention to this matter and thank you in advance.

My playbook:

```
---
- hosts: device-01
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: sv_admin
  connection: paramiko
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /root/.ssh/m2q_id_rsa
    #ansible_ssh_pass: /root/.ssh/m2q_passphrase
  tasks:
    - name: Check Paramiko privilege escalation
      command: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - id
        - pwd
        - 'sv_enable sv_admin'
        - id
      register: shell_output
    - debug: var=shell_output
    - debug:
        msg: hello
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you've already found the answer:

1. escalate privilege by doing whatever you said, in this case "sv_enable sv_admin".
2. utilize "id", "whoami", "w", "who" or something alike to, for certain, know that any privilege even has escalated.
3. utilize "passwd" on the EUID or UID (depending on situation: but usually the lower numbers the better/"more privileges") to permanently change the login-password...

Now I have never used Ansible, but it is based on python so the functionality should be readily available to read. Tip: use "strace" and/or "ltrace" to find out what happens and/or how the program translates the "sv_enable sv_admin" command. If it there is a series of setuid, setgid, seteuid, setegid, serreuid, etc... then sudo would essentially also work - remember: man sudo. <--- There is alot of options to uncover this issue using only logic thinking.